# Microsoft Graph API 403 - Could not obtain a WAC access token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, wac

I have an integration with the Microsoft Graph API to read and write Excel files on OneDrive.

I am suddenly getting the errors:

HTTP Error occurred: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/%5C*%5C*%5C*/workbook/worksheets

Response Content: {"error":{"code":"AccessDenied","message":"Could not obtain a WAC access token.","innerError"....}}

I can still read the titles of the files through the API but cannot write to them. My code has not changed and my permissions are still the same with read/write.all etc and it was working less than 2 days ago.

I have tried removing the connection and re-authenticating, trying different Excel files, and ensuring they all have .xlsx extension however the error persists.

Comment: Are you able to create a session?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-createsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: No I have not needed to use the session.

Comment: I have the same issue, was working for a while and suddenly I get this error, did you find a solution?

Comment: @user2250152 I tried to create a session but get the same error

Comment: I believe it may have been from using a free account and suddenly detected. I have not tried with a 365 account yet.